# How do I get the id of the affected row with _after_update in web2py?

Tags: web2py

I have a table structure such as:

```
entity
entity_like
```

Where `entity_like` contains user likes regarding the entity.  In order to avoid having to calculate the total likes every time I view an entity I'm caching the total likes inside the `entity` table.  Now whenever a new entity_like is inserted or updated I want to update the cache.

My thought is to use [`_after_insert`](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#before-and-after-callbacks) and [`_after_update`](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#before-and-after-callbacks) to calculate the new cached like total and store it in the entity object.

This is straight-forward with `_after_insert` as you are provided with the id of the inserted record.  However with `_after_update` the id is not provided.  How do I get the id of the updated record from within `_after_update`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_after_update` callback takes the DAL `Set` object, which is used to identify the record(s) to be updated. So, you can do a `.select()` on the Set in order to get the updated record(s) (including their id's):

```
def after_el_update(s, fields):
    ids = [r.id for r in s.select()]
    ...
```